# Do I need to take ownership to be able to delete/move files?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba

I run `bittorrent-nox` on my little seed box and since I switched from NTFS to ext4 now sometimes the files will not let me edit them over SAMBA file share - it tells me I need to be the bittorrent nox user. When I was using NTFS I had them mounted with fstab using `uid=1000, gid=1000, nofail, umask=000` so everyone could edit them.

I did not change SAMBA settings since changing the file system.

What do I need to do to allow my remote windows users to edit the files?